# Facebook Login in spritekit always returns canceled

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, facebook, sprite-kit

I'm currently using the code below to sign in with facebook using a custom sprite node button:

```
func runLoginForFacebook() {

     print("logging in with facebook...")
     print("FACEBOOK CURRENT TOKEN ---->\(FBSDKAccessToken.current())")

     let login = FBSDKLoginManager()
     let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
     login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: viewController, handler: { result, error in

    if error != nil {
        print("Process error \(error!.localizedDescription)")
    } else if result?.isCancelled != nil {
        print("Cancelled \(error?.localizedDescription)")
    } else {
        print("Logged in")
        signIntoFirebase()
    }
  })
}
```

now this allows me to login and hit continue button so the screen is dismissed but it always returns isCanceled as yes instead of logging in.

I have searched all over this website for answers and they all say the app delegate is the problem here is my app delegate which seems to be fine:

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, MessagingDelegate {

var window: UIWindow?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions:

   return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    let handled: Bool = FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.sourceApplication] as? String, annotation: options[UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey.annotation])
    // Add any custom logic here.

    return handled
}
```

The next solution was that I didn't have any test users in my app in the developer portal on facebook which I checked and that was not the case I have the same account I used to login as a test user/admin for the app.

Also I checked my info.plist file and everything seems to be fine (see below. **I PUT THE XXXXs IN THE NAME AND NUMBERS FOR PRIVACY REASONS** the number checks out fine and is the same as the developer portals ID)

```
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
    <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
</array>
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fb4961923108XXXXX</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>496192XXXXXXXX</string>
<key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
<string>NaXXX</string>
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>fbapi</string>
    <string>fb-messenger-share-api</string>
    <string>fbauth2</string>
    <string>fbshareextension</string>
</array>
```

Can someone help me? any ideas would be greatly appreciated because i've been at this for a day and I can't figure it out.

Comment: Can you share any sample project?

Comment: @Dharmesh sorry I can’t you could try using my login code and app delegate code in a Blank SpriteKit project. The login function isn’t in any class at the moment it’s just a global function in my SpriteKit project

Comment: You are only checking if result?.isCancelled != nil,  you need to be checking if isCancelled is false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking `if result?.isCancelled` is not nil, so if you have a result, it will always be true or false, never nil.  Try the following code instead (note this is not tested, so if I messed up syntax, feel free to edit my answer with the correct code)

```
func runLoginForFacebook() {

     print("logging in with facebook...")
     print("FACEBOOK CURRENT TOKEN ---->\(FBSDKAccessToken.current())")

     let login = FBSDKLoginManager()
     let viewController = UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController
     login.logIn(withReadPermissions: ["public_profile"], from: viewController, handler: { result, error in

          guard let result = result else {
              print("No result found")
          }
          if result.isCancelled {
              print("Cancelled \(error?.localizedDescription)")

          } else if let error = error {
              print("Process error \(error.localizedDescription)")
          } else {
              print("Logged in")
              signIntoFirebase()
          }
     })
}
```

Comment: Yeah that worked perfectly!!! I found my code on the facebook developer documentation site, can't believe they gave me the wrong code, thanks again.